# Call a UIViewController from within a UIControl's touchUpInside method

Tags: iphone

I have a button that I'm creating in a `UIViewController` like so:

```
TOLoginButton* button = [[[TOLoginButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,180,200,40)] autorelease];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

The button is a `UIControl` and I'm trying to call another `UIViewController` from within the `touchUpInside` method, below is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
- (void)touchUpInside {

    MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [super.view addSubview:viewController.view ];
}
```

I'm basically trying to call this `viewController` once my button is pressed.

So `viewController1` has the button on it and once the button is pressed I want to do something like `[viewController1.view addSubview:viewController2.view]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the new `UIViewController` is full-screen, the more usual thing to do is

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or if you're using a navigation controller

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: The problem is that self is a UIControl so are yo saying you can call presentModalViewController on a UIControll, cause it gives errors if you do?

Comment: ah, sorry, that code was meant to live in a UIViewController subclass.  I've only used interface builder to add UIControls, so I'm not entirely sure, but I think what you need to do is call [button addTarget:self action:@selector("buttonWasPressed") forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] which will tell the button to run the "buttonWasPressed" method in your view controller, and then you can load the other view controller from there.